# Modulo calculation with multiple exponents, via CRT

Tags: modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

I'm aware that there are already a few questions like this but unfortunately I wasn't able to find an answer yet.

$$ (14^{2014)^{2014}} \pmod {60} $$

So I started off by putting the modular in :
$$ (14^{2014}\pmod{60})^{2014} $$

So I looked at the inner break first and decided to calculate the inside.
Since $gcd(14,60) \not= 1$ I can't use Euler/Fermat and have to do it via prime factorization and if Euler/Fermat works than this, otherwise I would have used CRT.

$$ 60 = 5*3*2^2$$
$$14^{2014} \equiv 1 \pmod 5$$
$$14^{2014} \equiv 1 \pmod 3$$
$$14^{2014} \equiv 0 \pmod 2$$

So 
$$14^{2014} \equiv 2 \pmod {60}$$

I now have left:
$$2^{2014} \pmod {60}$$

Then I used CRT again, well I wanted to but saw that was actually easier again to get the values using Euler/Fermat after prime factorization like above.
$$2^{2014} \equiv 4 \pmod {5}$$
$$2^{2014} \equiv 1 \pmod {3}$$
$$2^{2014} \equiv 0 \pmod {2}$$

So I assumed that it is 4 and
$$2^{2014} \equiv 0 \pmod {4}$$

So
$$2^{2014} \equiv 4 \pmod {60}$$

Unfortunately 4 is not the answer our tutor told us, he meant that the correct result is 16. Can anyone find where I miscalculated or where I was thinking wrong?

Edit: 
Actually I found one answer if I start off in another way:

$$14^{2014*2014} \pmod {60}$$

If I then do prime factorization and look at the remainders of the exponent I found that
$$ 2014*2014 \equiv 2 \pmod {60}$$
and therefore 
$$14^2 = 196$$
$$196 \pmod{60} = 16$$

Great! Still, if anyone knows why the other approach doesn't work please tell me.

Edit 2: I thought about it and I'm not sure if I'm allowed to just look at the exponents instanced. Maybe it's just coincidence.
Edit 3: To the post with the similar question: The solution is not fully the same and I think in this post it is easier to understand. Furthermore it was nice if this question stays because I wanted to show it to my peers.

Comment: possible duplicate of [(14^2014)^2014 mod 60 without a calculator](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1264259/1420142014-mod-60-without-a-calculator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conclusion

$14^{2014}≡2 (60)$

is not correct. It should be

$14^{2014}≡16 (60)$.

Here is my computation:

$14^{2014}≡1(5)$

$14^{2014}≡1(3)$

$14^{2014}≡0(4)$

And hence also:

$(14^{2014})^{2014}≡1(5)$

$(14^{2014})^{2014}≡1(3)$

$(14^{2014})^{2014}≡0(4)$

Therefore:

$(14^{2014})^{2014}≡16(60)$

Comment: Ah I see I have to take 4 if primal factorization = 5*3*2*2 and not just 2. I see why $14^{2014} \pmod {60} $ is cong. 16. 
Thank you very much for taking the time! Appreciate.